# Jerky Cloth Simulation

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, cloth-simulation

I have a cloth simulation that I rendered as a PNG sequence and played out as an mp4 in Adobe Premiere. Unfortunately, the video has become quite jerky. At the beginning when the Cloth Sim starts it jerks briefly and while the simulation is playing it keeps shaking briefly. I can not explain this. Does it have to do with the settings in the Cloth Sim? Thanks for your help!

I have also added the png sequence. Maybe the error has something to do with the render of the sequence.

[MP4](https://we.tl/t-MG7qXnRmPi)
[Blender File](https://we.tl/t-wdjI8EfuSb)
[PNG Sequence](https://we.tl/t-NBYZieIPLX)

Comment: Are we talking about it is stopping in some frames or about that it first act like plane and after landing it will start to act like cloth?

Comment: MikoCG are there different reasons for that? The stopping frames are bothering me even more. But actually I would be interested in solving both issues. thank you!

Comment: Well the difference is that when I rendered it, there was no stopping frames... that's weird actually, but maybe it was due to baking, did you bake it? As for the other issue it can be solved with changing settings... maybe there is a different solution as well but changing Compression values to 0 makes it fold faster without that stop

Comment: MikoCG very kind of you!! No I didn‘t bake it. I will try it out. Did you render it as png sequence? Thank you I will try the settings fot th other issue.

Comment: No, I have rendered it as MP4, maybe it makes difference as well... did you make it into mp4 in blender video editing? Maybe some frames are duplicated or something... btw Compression in Stiffness, not Damping... I am going to try render it as png sequence to see if it changes something

Comment: MikoCG I see! No I used Adobe Premiere. Maybe thats the problem. Can you import the png sequence in blender and render it as mp4 afterward?

Comment: yes you can, you can also directly render it as mp4, from file format options select FFmpeg and in Encoding change Matroska to MPEG-4, your render will be mp4... and importing image sequence, just tap on Add and there will be Image/sequence

Comment: Setting the compression to 0 works just fine. Amazing! Thank you. The stopping frame issue is still there when I try to import it to the sequencer and export it to mp4 but it seems to work when I export it as an mp4 right away.